# Can't populate an array with data returned from mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
var array = [];
Collection.findOne({'name' : 'FirstItem'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    array.push(result);
});
```

Now mongoose returns result as it should, but I can't add it to the array - it remains empty. What's the problem?

Comment: Where did you check the array? Is `Collection.findOne` not a `async` function?

Comment: does the `result`contain data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write code like:

```
var array = [];
Collection.findOne({'name' : 'FirstItem'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    array.push(result);
});
// Do something with the array.
console.log(array);
```

The `array` will be empty at there, because when you call `Collection.findOne`, it needs to connect to your database and retrieve the data, and this will cost time.

And for the reason not blocking your succeeding codes, it'll not just hang there and wait to receive the result, instead, it'll let other codes still run, and call the funtion you passed in when it got data, until then, your `array` will be empty

What you should do is move your logic that needs to use the `array`, in to that callback, like:

```
var array = [];
Collection.findOne({'name' : 'FirstItem'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    array.push(result);
    // Do something with the array.
    console.log(array);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it now works. I am not a back-end expert and I don't have much experience with these things.